# How to reverse SASS for loop on 4th nth-child?

Tags: html, sass, css-selectors

I have a loop of divs and I want the sequence of say 24 divs to go as follows:

red > orange > yellow > green > green > yellow > orange > red ... and repeat.

So basically it works in lots of 8 and does 4 colours then reverses them colours. After searching online I came across this code which does the first half of the job but I'm finding it difficult to understand how I would reverse the sequence.

I realise that you could write...

```
$colors: red, orange, yellow, green, green, yellow, orange, red;
```

However I thought there might be a shorter way of writing it than that?

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
  <li>d</li>
  <li>e</li>
  <li>f</li>
  <li>g</li>
  <li>h</li>
</ul>
```

SCSS:

```
$colors: red, orange, yellow, green;

@for $i from 1 through length($colors) {
  li:nth-child(#{length($colors)}n+#{$i}) {
    background: lighten(nth($colors, $i), 20%);
  }
}
```

Heres a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b1sLdmnj/) of what i have so far, hopefully what I want to achieve makes sense and someone might be able to explain how I go about achieving it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Would you be happy with solution like this :

```
$colors: red, orange, yellow, green, green, yellow, orange, red;

@for $i from 1 through length($colors) {
    li:nth-child(#{length($colors)}n+#{$i}) {
        background: lighten(nth($colors, $i), 20%);
    }
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qn4zb8e6/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had thought of that and that works but i thought maybe there was a better way of writing it? A shorter version?

Comment: @user2498890 Would be nice then to say that in original post before people waste time giving you correct answers on wrong questions...

Comment: Ok sure thanks for the suggestion I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest way to do it is to have your list contain exactly the values you want to cycle through.  For your short example, writing them out by hand is going to be the shortest way to do so.  If it's a long list, then rolling your own list-reverse function and joining the lists might be preferable.

```
@function list-reverse($xs) {
    $collector: ();

    @for $i from length($xs) through 1 {
        $collector: append($collector, nth($xs, $i));
    }
    @return $collector;
}

$colors: red, orange, yellow, green;
$color-list: join($colors, list-reverse($colors));

@for $i from 1 through length($color-list) {
  li:nth-child(#{length($color-list)}n+#{$i}) {
    background: lighten(nth($color-list, $i), 20%);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for you answer so just to confirm are you saying that in my case it would be better just to write the colours in reverse like i have in my question or are you saying the code you have suggested is better? I tried implementing your code but can't seem to get it to work. Not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: "Better" is subjective here.  Avoiding repetition can sometimes force you to write a lot more code.  Demo: http://sassmeister.com/gist/942c43ce50daedf34000

Answer (score 1):

Or use a condition :

```
$colors: red, orange, yellow, green;
$n : 0;
@for $i from 1 through 2*length($colors) {
  @if $i > length($colors) {
    $n : $n - 1;
  } @else {
    $n : $i;
  }
  @if $i == length($colors)+1 { $n : $n+1;}

  li:nth-child(#{length($colors)}n+#{$i}) {
    background: lighten(nth($colors, $n), 20%);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer this has worked perfectly. Being new to conditions with SASS would you mind commenting to help me fully understand what the code is doing?

Comment: Also i put it in this jsfiddle to test it worked - http://jsfiddle.net/b1sLdmnj/1/

Comment: Ok I just noticed it works for the first 8 but then doesn't continue the sequence thereafter any idea why this might be?